# different eigenvalues from np.eig and np.svd

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, svd

I'm comparing the eigenvalues computed by np.eig(np.dot(A.T, A))**2 and np.eig(A).
I found some values are the same but some are not. Can anybody tell me why would this happen?

Comment: Post a minimal, complete, verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

There is no mathematical reason to expect that the eigenvalues of A should be equal to the squares of the eigenvalues of (A.T * A).  For example, the eigenvalues of A might be complex, whereas the eigenvalues of A.T * A are guaranteed to be real because A.T * A is a symmetric matrix.